# inheritance with virtual protected method

Tags: c++, swig

I am trying to wrapper some classes from c++ to c# with swig and it is work pretty good.
Suddenly I tried to call some method and my program crash.
My class flow looks like this(only the important classes):
c++ code:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void f1();
protected:
    int f2();
};
class D:public B
{
public:
    virtual void f1();
protected:
    float f3();
};
```

This classes make swig to generate for each class a SwigDirector.
And in my c# code I try to do something like this:

    `public class Foo:D
    {
        void callF2Meth()
        {
            this.f2();
        }
    }`

> The exception is thrown on d.f2();
>   In the code that swig generate the method to call f2 look like this(with out initialization):
>   
>     `arg1 = (Base *)jarg1; 
>     darg = dynamic_cast<SwigDirector_B *>(arg1);
>     result = (int)(darg)->f2();`
>   
>   The exception is thrown because arg1 is type of SwigDirector_D that not inheritance from SwigDirector_B but from D(witch also do not inheritance from SwigDirector_B but from B)
>    
>   The swig code:

```
  %module(directors="1", allprotected="1") SwigExample
  %{
  #include "Base.h"
  #include "Derived.h"
  %}
  %feature("director") Base;
  %feature("director") Derived;
  %include "Base.h"
  %include "Derived.h"
```

So I did some debugging and I realized that swig trying to convert SwigDirector of D to SwigDirector of B witch not in the same hierarchy.
How can I tell swig to correct wrapping the classes?

Comment: Know nothing of swig, but a side note: your title mentions a protected member, while all your members in code are private...

Comment: When inheriting protected member functions, they can be called from inside the derived class but not from the outside. If you want to be able to call f2 on a D object, don't make f2 protected, make it public.

Comment: `D d=new D();` that is not right. You either allocate on heap or stack, but what is this mix ? Moreover you are accessing a protected function from nowhere. Protected means only inherited class and the class itself can see it.

Comment: My code example was with too many error. I fixed it and now it is correct.

Comment: Did you really do `this.f2()`? AFAIK it's not allowed in C++.

Comment: Without seeing a complete example of exactly how you're using this code it';s difficult to give you much help. I'd suggest using C++-CLI to create a wrapper instead as you have more precise control over how your interface it created...

Comment: All the idea of swig is that my code is in c++ and it create wrapper classes in c#. So this.f2() is legal in c#

Comment: There is no such thing as a `D` object in C#, only a wrapper of `D`. Therefore, your `this` refers to the wrapper, and not a class of type `D`. Calling `f2()` on `this` is therefore **not** calling the method from inside a class `D` at all.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am inheritance from the derived wrapper class in c# too

Comment: It is a shot in the dark, but have you used the [allprotected](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_allprotected) option?

Comment: Yes.the swig generate all the class correctly.

Comment: This crashing happens only with classes with virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known limitation/bug in SWIG (see  my question on the [SWIG-mailinglist](https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/mailman/message/35136476/)). I chose to workaround this issue by implementing D::f2(){ return B::f2(); }.